# Deleting current song when clearing queue on sonos iOS

Tags: ios, queue, sonos

Im using [sonos-objc](https://github.com/getSenic/sonos-objc/) class to control sonos from iOS app

When i want to play track i call this method "playSpotifyTrack" and after clearing the queue the current song still playing and when it finish it stay

how i can remove it ?

------**Solution**-------

```
- (void)playSpotifyTrack:(NSString *)track position:(int)position completion:(void (^)(NSDictionary *reponse, NSError *error))block {

    NSString *trackURI = [track stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"%%3a"];

    NSString *meta = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                      @"<DIDL-Lite xmlns:dc=\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\" xmlns:upnp=\"urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/\" xmlns:r=\"urn:schemas-rinconnetworks-com:metadata-1-0/\" xmlns=\"urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/\"> \
                      <item id=\"10030020%@\" parentID=\"10030020\" restricted=\"true\"> \
                      <upnp:class>object.item.audioItem.musicTrack</upnp:class> \
                      <desc id=\"cdudn\" nameSpace=\"urn:schemas-rinconnetworks-com:metadata-1-0/\">SA_RINCON2311_X_#Svc2311-0-Token</desc> \
                      </item> \
                      </DIDL-Lite>", trackURI];

    meta = [[[meta stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@"&lt;"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@"&gt;"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"&quot;"];

    [self
     upnp:@"/MediaRenderer/AVTransport/Control"
     soap_service:@"urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1"
     soap_action:@"AddURIToQueue"
     soap_arguments:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<InstanceID>0</InstanceID><EnqueuedURI>10060a6c%@</EnqueuedURI><EnqueuedURIMetaData>%@</EnqueuedURIMetaData><DesiredFirstTrackNumberEnqueued>%d</DesiredFirstTrackNumberEnqueued><EnqueueAsNext>0</EnqueueAsNext>", trackURI, meta, position]
     completion:^(id response, NSError *error) {
         if(error) {
             if(block) {
                 block(response, error);
                 return;
             }
         }
         [self playQueuePosition:position completion:block];
     }];
}
```

The solution is I add track to queue and then i play it by calling "playQueuePosition" instead of playing direcly

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint inside the completion block to see what, if any, errors are returned?

Comment: There is no error, cause the queue is cleared but song still playing

Comment: Hmmm been a while since I've tried it, but maybe that's by design? Looking at the [API ref for playlists](http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/331) it doesn't look like it explicitly stops playback; moreover, `RemoveAllTracksFromQueue` isn't even in the docs anymore -- maybe that lib is using an older version of the API?

Comment: I figured out my problem, post updated for anyone who have the same problem

Comment: You're better off to add an answer and mark it as accepted for people too see the solution in the future  Glad you got it working!